# Formatting data with a foreach in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to make an API call with the data formatted like this.

```
[{"Id":10, “FolderID”:22},{"Id":12, “FolderID”:22}]
```

I have these different data sources below: (using redux)

```
const FolderId = indexes.currentFolder.id;
```

This is a constant value

```
const documentsId = indexes.copyDocuments;
```

this is the format of 8, 9 , 10

I tried to implement it by looping through the documents array
with a foreach.

The only way i know how to attach the data is with an array but this creates a new array of each loop with is not what i want.

```
const data = [];

documentsId.forEach(function(doc){
  data.push(`"Id":${doc},"FolderID":${FolderId}`)
})
```

Does anyone know a way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: maybe try something along the lines of:
`var tmp = {};
tmp.Id = doc.Id; tmp.FolderId = doc.FolderId;
data.push(tmp);`

Comment: what you want to do is quite simple. But can you provide more details on your arrays. Console what is documentsId .

Comment: I'm not sure how you're passing the `FolderId`  in the following `data.push(`"Id":${doc},"FolderID":${FolderId}`)` . If you're pushing an object to your array you can use   ```data.push({"Id":`${doc}`,"FolderID":`${FolderId}`}```.

Comment: Array 0
:
50
1
:
49
length
:
2.

Comment: when i try an use an object instead of an array it says its undefined

Comment: You aren't creating _arrays_. You're creating an array of _strings_.

Comment: Are you saying that (1) the _result_ you want after formatting your data is `[{"Id":10, “FolderID”:22},{"Id":12, “FolderID”:22}]` **?** Or (2) is that what your data looks like, and you want to format it somehow?  If it's #1 tell us what the original data looks like. If it's #2 tell us what the desired result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things you're passing into the `data` array are *strings*, when what you want is *objects*. Instead of:

```
data.push(`"Id":${doc},"FolderID":${FolderId}`)
```

....do:

```
data.push({ Id: doc, FolderID: FolderId })
```

...and `data` will be an array of *objects* instead of *strings*.

I'd also recommend using `map` like @JoeWarner suggested as a more succinct way to build the Array.

```
const data = documentsId.map(doc => ({ Id: doc, FolderID: FolderId }))
```

Answer (score 2):

What i believe you're looking for is the map prototype

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

what map does is return a new array from an orignal array so in your example we have an array of

```
[8, 9, 10]
```

we map over this the same way we'd use `forEach` it gets passed the item then the index

```
const newArray = [8, 9, 10].map(function (item, index) {
  return [item, index]
})
// [[8, 0], [9, 1], [10, 2]]
```

the map prototype returns a NEW array so no need to copy your array as to not mutate it this makes the map prototype immutable

```js
const documentsId = [8, 9, 10]

/* however you get your folderId */
const folderId = 22;

const mappedToObjectArray = documentsId.map(id => ({id, folderId}))


/*
  If you're used to es5 this might look more familiar 

  function formatData() {
    return documentsId.map(function (doc) {
      return {
        id: doc,
        folderId: folderId
      }
    })
  }
*/

console.log(mappedToObjectArray)
```

Please let me know if i've misunderstood or you're confused about anything happy to help.